# Why don't CMake arguments work when defined in gradle flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I want the CMakeLists.txt for my Android app to link different libraries depending on the product flavor being built. Here's the code from CMakeLists.txt.

```
# Link all libraries
if (DEFINED VULKAN_VALIDATION_ON)
    target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} libVkLayer_khronos_validation )
    message("Vulkan validation fully linked.")
else()
    target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} )
    message("Vulkan validation NOT linked.")
endif()
```

I define VULKAN_VALIDATION_ON in my app's build.gradle as follows.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++17"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "PlayStore"
    productFlavors {
        development {
            dimension "PlayStore"
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPLAY_STORE=TRUE -DVULKAN_VALIDATION_ON=TRUE"
                }
            }
        }
        production {
            dimension "PlayStore"
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPLAY_STORE=TRUE"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.22.1"
        }
    }
}
```

When building the "developmentDebug" flavor dimension I expect to see "**Vulkan validation fully linked.**" but instead I see "**Vulkan validation NOT linked.**"

I've looked at similar questions on Stack Overflow and this is the way people recommend passing arguments to CMake using flavors. So why would it not be working for me?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to leave this question rather than delete it because I believe others will encounter this problem in the future.

The problem was that multiple cmake arguments have to be defined differently than I'd done above. Changing them thusly fixed the problem.

```
    cmake {
        arguments "-DPLAY_STORE=TRUE", "-DVULKAN_VALIDATION_ON=TRUE"
    }
```